# How i can pass values from one page to another with the help of select option in php?

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I have a simple code where i query my database, and set the values in a option list, as shown in the code below :

```
    <?php
        $postQuery="SELECT DISTINCT labelName FROM posts";
        $postResult=mysqli_query($conn,$postQuery);
     ?>


    <form action="inc/set.php" method="post" enctype="multiform/partdata">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="Add Title"><br>
        <select name="lable" >

            <option value="empty">Empty</option>

            <?php foreach ($postResult as $post) {;?>

                <option value="<?php echo $post['labelname'];?>"><?php echo $post['labelName'];?> 
                </option>

            <?php } ;?>

        </select>
```

How can i pass the values from the option list that are in php code in the another page as shown in the form inc/set.php . And what would be the standart and best way to do that. Thank you for yo help folks.

Comment: you are using form and the method is post the value will be in **$_POST['lable']** 
but if you want to use it on other pages you can use $_SESSION or $_COOKIE** or save it to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a session variable! See: "PHP Sessions" at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).